# How do I keep a user Authenticated in DNN 5.6.6 when using RadEditor's Image Manager?

Tags: telerik, dotnetnuke-5

I have a RadEditor on a page, and it is breaking authentication on the next postback after I have closed the Image Manager Dialog.

I have tried adding this:

```
 reThePolicy.DialogOpener.AdditionalQueryString = string.Format("&PortalID={0}", PortalId);
```

in the codebehind, and in IE9 it fails the first time, but every other time thereafter it works. In other browsers, it never works.

Any help is appreciated

A little background -- this is only happening on child portals, and only for users that do not exist in other portals.

in the ascx  (the paths and whatnot are declared in the codebehind, but when the imagemanager pop-up doesn't kill authentication, that all works):

```
<telerik:RadEditor StripFormattingOptions="MSWordRemoveAll" ID="reThePolicy" runat="server"
            Width="769px" Style="margin: 6px;">
            <Content></Content>
        </telerik:RadEditor>
```

in my web config:

```
<htmlEditor defaultProvider="RadEditorProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear />
                <add name="FckHtmlEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.FckHtmlEditorProvider.FckHtmlEditorProvider, DotNetNuke.FckHtmlEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/" CustomConfigurationPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/custom/FCKConfig.js" EnhancedSecurityDefault="false" SecureConfigurationPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/custom/FCKConfigSecure.js" ImageGalleryPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fckimagegallery.aspx" ImageUploadPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fckimagegallery.aspx" ImageAllowedFileTypes="gif,png,bmp,jpg" FlashGalleryPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fckimagegallery.aspx" FlashUploadPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fckimagegallery.aspx" FlashAllowedFileTypes="fla,swf" LinksGalleryPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/fcklinkgallery.aspx" DynamicStylesGeneratorPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/FCKStyles.aspx" DynamicStylesCaseSensitive="true" DynamicStylesGeneratorFilter="controlpanel|filemanager|mainmenu|wizard" StaticStylesFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/FCKeditor/fckstyles.xml" StylesDefaultMode="Static" DynamicCSSGeneratorPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/FCKCSS.aspx" StaticCSSFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Fck/FCKeditor/editor/css/fck_editorarea.css" CSSDefaultMode="static" spellCheck="ieSpell" AvailableToolbarSkins="Office2003,Silver" DefaultToolbarSkin="Office2003" AvailableToolBarSets="DNNDefault,Default,NoGallery,Basic" DefaultToolbarSet="DNNDefault" DefaultImageGallerySkin="Default" DefaultFlashGallerySkin="Default" DefaultLinksGallerySkin="Default" FCKDebugMode="false" UseFCKSource="false" OptionsOpenMode="ShowModalDialog" CustomOptionsDialog="Admin" />
                <add name="RadEditorProvider" type="Telerik.DNN.Providers.RadEditorProvider" providerPath="~/DesktopModules/TelerikWebUI" AutoCreatePaths="true" />
                <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.4.2 - Date: 11/8/2010 4:07:51 PM-->
                <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
                <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.4.2 - Date: 11/20/2010 12:52:19 AM-->
                <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
                <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.6.0 - Date: 11/20/2010 12:52:20 AM-->
                <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
                <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.6.3 - Date: 9/14/2011 9:51:59 AM-->
                <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
                <!--Upgraded by DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider version 5.6.3 - Date: 1/19/2012 12:44:58 PM-->
                <!--<add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />-->
                <add name="TelerikEditorProvider" type="DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider.EditorProvider, DotNetNuke.HtmlEditor.TelerikEditorProvider" providerPath="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/" toolsFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ToolsDefault.xml" configFile="~/Providers/HtmlEditorProviders/Telerik/Config/ConfigDefault.xml" FilterHostExtensions="True" />
            </providers>
        </htmlEditor>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I posted this on a number of Forums, and I got the answer from Telerik.

Their suggestion, although humorous [Don't use our product :D ]

was the one that worked. It is:

Our suggestion is to not use the -telerik:RadEditor- in the ascx file as a standalone control in DNN, but to use the integrated in DNN -dnn:TextEditor- control.

Please, also note that DotNetNuke.TelerikEditorProvider provider of RadEditor is developed and supported by DNN Corp only.